# Vector fields on the product manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Regarding the isomorphism $T_{(x,y)}(X \times Y)= T_xX\times T_yY$ between the tangent spaces of two manifolds $X$ and $Y$, is it true that $$\mathfrak{X}(X \times Y)=\mathfrak{X}(X) \oplus \mathfrak{X}(Y),$$
where $\mathfrak{X}(-)$ denotes the module of vector fields?

Comment: See if you can use the map used to prove the isomorphism to show something about the maps on the module level.

Comment: @A.Goodier The theorem that you have refered to have different meaning than $\mathfrak{X}(M \times N) = \mathfrak{X}(M) \oplus \mathfrak{X}(N)$.